# Please clarify regarding the -z and -n options for testing variables in bash

Tags: bash

I am just going through the basics of bash and I have a question regarding the `-z` and `-n` option for the test or [..] command.

AFAIK  `[-z $var ]` returns true if `$var` is empty or null
and `[-n $var ]` returns true if `$var` is non-empty.

But I have the following output

```
[root@localhost ~]# COLUMNS="";[ -z $COLUMNS ] && echo tru || echo fals
tru
[root@localhost ~]# COLUMNS="abc";[ -z $COLUMNS ] && echo tru || echo fals
fals
[root@localhost ~]# COLUMNS="abc";[ -n $COLUMNS ] && echo tru || echo fals
tru
[root@localhost ~]# COLUMNS="";[ -n $COLUMNS ] && echo tru || echo fals
tru
[root@localhost ~]# COLUMNS="abc";[ -n $COLUMN ] && echo tru || echo fals
tru
```

Can someone explain, why the fourth line returned true when the variable is empty?
I have not set the value of COLUMN, but still, the fifth line returns true?
can someone please explain when in what cases will `[ -n $var ]` return false by giving examples?

Comment: You might be interested in checking out [`shellcheck`](http://www.shellcheck.net/), an online and/or command-line tool qualifying your shell code. In your case, it would have reported that `-n doesn't work with unquoted arguments. Quote or use [[ ]].` as the answers mention.

Comment: COLUMNS is a shell variable, try a different variable name for this.

Answer (score 2):

when using single `[` test variable expansion must be between double quotes to prevent word splitting.

As `[[` is a shell keyword bash can handle variable expansion without the need of double quotes.

-n and -z require a second argument which can be null (empty) but because double quotes are missing around variable, after word splitting there is no argument.

compare the two following commands

```
[ -n ]  && echo ok     #  or [ -n $varname ]
[ -n "" ]  && echo ok  #  or [ -n "$varname" ]
```

- if the number of arguments is 1 the result is true if argument is not empty

examples

```
[ '' ] # false
[ '-z *6548*-' ] # true
```

- if the number of arguments is 2 then the first must be a unary operator

examples

```
[ "arg1" "arg2" ] # arg1: unary operator expected
[ -z '' ] # true
```

- if the number of arguments is 3 then the second must be a binary operator

examples

```
[ "arg1" "arg2" "arg3" ] # arg2: binary operator expected
[ "abc" != "def" ] # true
```

Another way to check a variable is set and not empty using parameter expansion

```
[ -n "${varname:+X}" ] # to check variable is set and not empty
```

Comment: Could you please point to me any good online source that would give more information about the -n and -z string operators

Comment: for posix `[`: `man [`, for `[[` `man bash` then `/\[\[` (with `PAGER=less`

Answer (score 0):

First thing is first, **COLUMNS** is used by the shell so your example is off in a way that you wouldn’t expect. It’s best to use safe variable names, all caps are usually reserved for shell variables.

Now that that’s out of the way, the test operators are simple:

> -n STRING will return true if the length of STRING is nonzero
>
> -z STRING will return true if the length of STRING is zero

There’s no magic or weirdness happening, if anything just make sure to always use double quotes on your variables and make sure you’re using safe names.